# Drawing smooth regions like RegionPlot[] from a set of data points

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have a set of data points [githubdata](https://github.com/gunsuer/mathematica_data/blob/main/ground_7.csv) and I want to draw the smmooth region that they occupy. I want a result similar to what we get when we use RegionPlot[]. When I ListPlot[] my data, I get the following image

[image]

But I need a smoother image. I want to see the boundary marked by thick lines and smoothed out, just like when we plot something using RegionPlot[]

[image]

Any suggestions on how to achieve this with the given data set?

Comment: Your data file has only two coordinates.  Where did the $K$ values come from?  To see more "detail", you'll need to rotate the points.  Maybe:  `r = RotationTransform[-99.2 2 \[Pi]/360, Mean[data]];
ListPlot[r[data], PlotLabel -> "-99.2 degree rotation"]`.

Comment: K is detail, I have 2 more files like the one I have provided. They are regions for different K. These are all details. K has nothing to do with spatial coordinates. The data is alright as it is.